# android - instant notification from another mobile phone. how?

Tags: android, notifications

hi i have this awesome app that can work both for clients and business owners, so lets say a business owner is connected on one end and a client on another , the client can place an order of some kind (not revealing too much :D ) and what i want is the business owner to know the client just placed a new order, considering that both have the application. can someone point me on how to ?
i am working with Firebase Real Time Database i handle it pretty good , but what happens when the app is closed and the client just placed an order , it needs to pop up on the business owner side , i haven't tried notifications yet but i suppose its not to hard to understand i just want the business owner app to be triggered when an order is placed.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: even if its closed.

Comment: you should keep the database listeners, meaning not to remove them in the `OnStop()`

Comment: try to implement a background service, which act as a db listener

Comment: aha i thought about it but was not sure.

Comment: also how can i handle battery consumption ? cause in the firebase value listener checks for updates on its own does it check every 10 seconds or every minutes who knows... maybe a looping service with single event value listener instead of just keeping it open, any thoughts ?

Comment: btw , thank you for the quick response.

Comment: i tried to add a service and the firebase database ref inside it but it works only when the application is on i need it to work as a total background service but i think the authentication does not pass when the app is closed , how would i fix that ? please answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a background service, I actually did something like you need with Firebase, we need to inform some users that other user pressed a panic button. So here's a sample code of what I did, you'll need a sticky service and a firebase listener, I don't know if the current version works the same as I did but here's what you could use, or at least I can give you an idea of how to do what you need.

```
public class DummyService extends Service implements ValueEventListener, ChildEventListener {

private Query mRef;

public static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://your-firebase-url.firebaseio.com/";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // some stuff else you need to do

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    // this will be your main ref, it'll hear everything on your firebase db
    Firebase mFirebaseRoot = new Firebase(DummyService.FIREBASE_URL);
    mRef = mFirebaseRoot;
    // if you want to hear an specific query you could use something like I used
    // you can read the docs at firebase web
    //mRef = mFirebaseRoot.child("your_child);
    mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(this);
    mRef.addChildEventListener(this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    // read the docs of how this listeners work
    if (something) {
        notifyUser();
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}

}
```

And you could use a BroadcastReceiver to catch when the device starts and fire your service, so this way user won't need to open the app and it'll always be running.

Hope this will be useful, sorry for the code sample indents, I don't why looks like this way haha.

Comment: this dosent seem to compile

Comment: Firebase as an object dose not exists, maybe i should try something else

Comment: i cant use this code as fire-base was updated the objects you are referring to are invalid, please some one...